# jquery создание полноценной таблицы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

получаю кучу информации через ajax (человек просто вбивает в поиске нужное слово и получает кучу инфы), и ее нужно красиво вывести. То есть создать div, внутри него еще 4 div. И так 10 раз. При этом, каждый раз, когда человек пользуется поиском, предыдущие результаты должны стираться. Мои познания в jquery дальше банальных append() и html() не позволяют решить задачку. Подкиньте идеи пожалуйста, как и чем это можно решить

Comment: Например гуглом: http://ajaxs.ru/lesson/ajax/132-zhivoj_poisk.html

Comment: мой поиск по факту кидает запрос и получает Json от itunes и далее все это в норм виде выводить должен)) пока что просто выводит. Я не имел ввиду поиск по самому сайту, сории

Comment: Ну на счет ITunes наверное стоит добвить в вопрос. Но если в целом то по идее смысл тот же, просто нужно немного переделать код. Почитатйте ту статью, разберитесь в структуре кода и потом сможете подстроить под себя.

Comment: у меня просто все, что в том коде написано, итак реализовано)) хотя я уже если честно продвинулся дальше, правда через те же append и appendTo, просто теперь сношу все перед каждым запросом пустым html(' '), запрос после каждого набора символа строится долго, но зато теперь правильно))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим на странице уже имеется div с id='content' куда и будем помещать данные.
Ты берешь свой AJAX ответ и считаешь сколько он вернул результатов поиска. Допустим их 3. Значит тебе 3 раза нужно вставить в div с id='content' по 4 дива (вложенных). Ниже кину функции, которые тебе помогут.

```
var content = $('div#content'); //наш див с результатами поиска
content.empty(); //очистит все внутри него;


var data = [{name:'Миша',age:'17'}, {name:'Саша',age:'18'}]; //допустим так выглядит твой АЯКС ответ
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { //объявляем цикл с количеством итераций равной количеству данный в ответе
    content.append('\
        <div class="main">\
            <div>\
                <div>' + data[i].name + '</div>\
                <div>' + data[i].age + '</div>\
            </div>\
        </div>\
    ');
}
```

Вопрос не полон, поэтому отвечаю абстрактно.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, правда я решил уже эту задачку))